# how to handle response of application/excel type in java

Tags: java, javascript, browser, httpresponse

I am trying to download one Excel file which is creating at run time only. Means Once I click on download, I got request in my Servlet, Then I write my file in response and set it's type as

```
response.setContentType("application/excel");
```

Now once this resopnse comes on browser, browser automatically open download popup and file downloading get started.

Now my problem is, I want to block my user to access application immediate after he clicks on download file till opening browser's download popup.

I can block user once he click on download, but don't know how to handle response of application/excel type.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Http header fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)
[rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1)

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "Binary");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+fileName+"\"");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how I can get the response on my jsp and when file download popup will open my browser? Please guide